# virtualbox not showing attached usb devices?

Tags: usb, kali-linux, virtualbox

I'm running virtual box in windows 7 and using Kali linux as guest OS. when I tried to add external adapter from devices menu I cant see any attached devices in usb port ?

Comment: Just to warn you this feature is VERY buggy in my experience depending on the device.  It often seems to require multiple removals, reinsertions, and reallocations to finally get the client linux to detect certain devices.  And storage devices may specifically require ejection from Windows.  Once the VM has it, it's fine usually.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing the VB Guest Additions on your host and restart once.